# Increment an enumeration using variable list lengths while mainting order in the enumeration

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have the following code

```
for i, v in enumerate(total_list):
    if isinstance(v[3], unicode):
        print i, len(v[3].split(';')), v[3].split(';')
```

which produces Nth items

```
93 1 [u'Nee']
94 6 [u'Bepalen van hoeveelheden materiaal', u'Energie-analyse', u'Verifi\xebren en valideren van ontwerpbeslissingen', u'Uitvoerbaarheid', u'Beheer & Onderhoud', u'']
95 3 [u'ArchiCAD', u'Solibri Model Checker', u'']
96 6 [u'IFC2x3 Coordination View', u'IFC4 Reference View', u'IFC4 Design Transfer View', u'gbXML', u'3D DWG', u'']
97 1 [u'Ja, de BIM Basis Informatie Leverings Specficatie (ILS)']
```

Now I want to use the list length to increment `i` while the enumeration keeps it order, this is the desired output:

```
93 1 [ u'Nee']
94 1 [ u'Bepalen van hoeveelheden materiaal']
95 1 [ u'Energie-analyse']
96 1 [ u'Verifi\xebren en valideren van ontwerpbeslissingen']
97 1 [ u'Uitvoerbaarheid']
98 1 [ u'Beheer & Onderhoud']
99 1 [u'ArchiCAD']
100 1 [u'Solibri Model Checker']
101 1 [u'IFC2x3 Coordination View']
102 1 [u'IFC4 Reference View']
103 1 [u'IFC4 Design Transfer View']
104 1 [ u'gbXML']
105 1 [u'3D DWG']
106 1 [u'Ja, de BIM Basis Informatie Leverings Specficatie (ILS)']
```

I have tried looping through the `v[3]` list and use the list length to increment the `i` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enumerate` isn't going to help you here. You need a global counter, independent of your loop "index", and an inner loop to print the values flat (increase the counter in this loop)

```
i = 0
for v in total_list:
    if isinstance(v[3], unicode):
        for tok in v[3].split(';'):
            print i, 1, tok
            i += 1
```